# Excel: Copy cell colour from a named range to a drop down menu

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me? I have a named range in `sheet1` and on `sheet2` cells that reference the named range as a drop down list. I want to copy the cell colour from the named range `sheet1` when it’s selected in the drop down list `sheet2`.
I’d be grateful for any support.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through VBA `Worksheet_change` event. Make sure that your colored range starts in cell `A1` on `sheet1`. then in sheet2 enter this code in `Worksheet module` (not `regular module`).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
      x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A1").Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange"), 0)
      Range("A1").Interior.Color = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & x).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

This code assumes you have your `data validation` cell in in cell `A1`, but you can adjust `Target.Adress` and `range("A1")` part of code to your needs.